# Does an android activity test class relate to an activity? or a use case?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have some test code working now. I created a MainActivityTest class to which I add my test methods, as several tutorials suggest. But now I am trying to figure out what I can and cannot do in that test class. When I look at structuring my test code, how do I decide to create another test class?

In the main test class, I can navigate to other activities and back. I have not tried anything else yet. If I have gotten to the second activity, is there something I will not be able to do with that activity's UI?

It seems to me that what my main activity test class has captured is actually a use case. In this test class, I am checking the navigation to the other activities. So, I am just checking if I can go there and back.

It seems that if I come up with a more complicated use case, I would want to put that in another activity test class. So the test class is not really about the activity, it is about the use case.

Sorry if this question is a bit meta. But use cases do not equate to activities in the android application. Would I be better dividing my test code up by activity or use case? It is not clear. The fact that the test class is called an "activity test class" may just be an artifact of history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you structure your tests is really what makes the most sense to you and how much time can you dedicate to building said tests.

As to the distinction between activities and use-cases - well I think an activity/fragment is comprised of 1 or more use-cases.  Additionally, use-cases can be broken down to 2 categories: functional/business.

**Functional**: navigation, event-handling - i.e. services, intents, orientation changes.  *Android's [functional testing guide](http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-functional-testing.html) defines it as how the application is expected to work.*

**Business**: the purpose of the activity.  Expected results from handling data.

The Android's [unit test guide](http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-unit-testing.html) talks about testing the smallest amount of code possible.

What makes sense to me was to test the capabilities of my activity/fragment:

- button behavior
- user inputs
- toolbar navigation
- listview
- ...etc

And then I created separate test objects for each of my activities/fragments/DAOs/content providers.  Each with their own unique test cases.

http://developer.android.com/training/testing.html might provide some better insight.